# SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have populated list items in a page with checkbox control with it and saved the checked items too in another list Now If I logged out and then login the same page it should show the checked items that I selected before.. How can I achieve this using javascript.

Comment: I have populated list items in a page with checkbox control with it and saved the checked items too in another list... till this I have done..

Comment: How did you save? Using javascript?

Comment: yes..all are done using JS... this is done for one column only of source list

Comment: That means you want to know how to get items from list using javascript?

Comment: I have fetched the list items and displayed them with checkbox control in a SharePoint page. Now as the items have checkbox I checked them and submitted them to save in another list (till this achieved).. Now I logged out from the SharePoint site and log in again here the previous checked items should show as checked ..(this one I need to achieve)

Comment: Ok. when you login again ..... get items from your list and populate check boxes with the data using javascript

Answer (score 0):

If i understand:

Create a javascript function that retrieve (as the same way you fill the items of checkbox)and execute a loop in all saved values in this new  list and find it in this page, so you check the control when you find.